# Show that $x\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right|$ is NOT of Bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let , $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right|&\text{ if } x\not=0\\0  &\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$$ is NOT a function of Bounded Variation.

If **modulus** is NOT given then using the partition $P=\{0,\frac{2}{2n+1},\cdots ,\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{3},1\}$I can show that total variation becomes infinite.

But for this case how I can show it is NOT of $BV$ ? What partition works for this function ?

Or any other way to show it is NOT of $BV$ ?

Comment: Just split your previous intervals in two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose subsequent $x_n$ (decreasing) such that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x_{2n}})= 0$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x_{2n+1}})= \pm 1$ (probably a refinement of your sequence)

Then the variation on each of these intervals is estimated from below a term of order $\frac{1}{n}$ (it *is* $x_{2n+1}$ if $x\sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ could be shown to be monotone on these intervals, but you need not really bother), so the sum of these is unbounded.

*Edit* in response to a comment, according to which it may not be possible the choose the $x_n$ as claimed:
with $x_{2n-1} = \frac{2}{2n+1} $ (for $n\ge 1$) we have $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x_{2n-1}})= \sin(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}) = \pm 1$
and with $x_{2n} = \frac{1}{n}$ ($n\ge 1$) we have $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x_{2n}})=\sin(n\pi) = 0$. It's easy to see that $x_n > x_{n+1}$. The region between $x_1$ and $0$ can be ignored, since it will only add to the variation.

(As mentioned earlier, this turns out to be a refinement of the sequence the OP used).

Comment: You can't just choose any sequence $x_n$ with those properties. Also I find the wording in the second paragraph strange.

Comment: @zhw why not? The zeros of $\sin$ are well known, as are the values for which this equals $1$, so you can just solve for $\pi/x$ to get such a sequence. The wording in the 2nd paragraph refers to the fact that you can evaluate the variation exactly if you have a monotonic function. If a function is (maybe) not monotonic but satisfies $f(a)= u$ and $f(b)=v$ then the variation between $a$ and $b$ is _at least_ $|u-v|$ (which is all what is needed here, so it's not necessary to care whether $x\sin(\pi/x)$ is monotonic between a zero and the next value where $\sin$ equals $1$

Comment: @zhw fixed a minor issue (added $\pm$ to the prescribed values of $\sin$ -- is this what bothered you?

Comment: @zhw I've written down the sequence explicitly. I really don't see what the problem is. Would you care to explain?

Comment: I suppose "subsequent" takes care of my objection. I thought you were taking any sequence $x_n$ that makes the $\sin$ take on those values, which won't work. I still don't understand the first sentence of the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @zhw. there was an additional embarassing typo, which i fixed. The funtion $|x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})|$ will take on the values $0$ for the $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ for the values $x_{2n+1}$, according to the values the $\sin$ function attains. Therefore, on the interval $[x_{2n}, x_{2n+1}]$ the variation is bounded from below by $x_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{2n+3}$, which is of order $\frac{1}{n}$ - this is true since the function increases by that amount, so the variation is at least that big. A similar reasoning applies to the interval $[x_{2n+1}, x_{2n+2}]$. My apologies, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: No problem.$\,$